# Managing custom post backend list table based on user info.- Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I am working with a multivendor electronic shop.The website has different roles.One of the roles are `shop owner`.Under this role different electronic shop owner can register.like owners for `whirlpool`, `singer` , `samsung`...etc.

Another function is `preorder`.Where one customer enters into a shop and through `preorder-form` they can `pre-order` different things on that shop.

Now i have a custom post `pre-order` where all the pre orders are shown in backend.For an administrator he can see all pre orders from all shops i.e: preorders from `whirlpool`, `singer` , `samsung`.

But the problem is to the `shop owner`.I want to show only preorders from their respective shop.Like preorders from `whirlpool` to `whirlpool shop owner`

Is there any way to show in this way in wp admin panel under pre-order post type?

---

> Note : i used [user role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).But its not that what i want.Also
>   i don't want to use plugin

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'pre_order_posts_filter' );

function pre_order_posts_filter( $query ) {

    global $post_type;      

    if ( 'pre-order' == $post_type && is_admin() ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( in_array( 'shop-owner', $current_user->roles ) ) {
            // filter only for user role `shop-owner` (please adjust)
            $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'author_id';
            $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $current_user->ID;               
        }

    }

}
```

You have to adjust it to your conditions.

Comment: This is an example. I don't know how the pre-orders associated with the shop owners. In my example I assume that the pre-orders have a metakey `shop_owner` that holds the User-ID of the shop-owner.

Comment: Yes You are absolutely right.It has author_id which is the id of the shop owner.but how i can use it?i.e: suppose author / shop-owner having ID : 1 - logged in and i want to show on `pre-order` page which have only author id: 1

Comment: Yes look at the picture : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1881164/e1867fa50be5a88786a977bfdcda07e7

Comment: Then my example should work. Make sure you use the right user role.

Comment: One more things please : How can i show only all , pending & published post? look at here : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1881347/a7210da1d2658901cf437372fa4ea086

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129043/discussion-between-beard-facial-and-andy-tschiersch).